# Android studio could not resolve retrofit2 converter scalars 2.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mobile, dependencies

Android studio displays this strange error whenever I add some dependency to the grade file. It was working perfectly earlier. Further it displays no cached version of retrofit2 scalars available for offline mode.
Currently I tried almost all options from uninstalling and reinstalling android studio but no luck. I am running out of time so please help me resolve this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.protabler"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha05'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.



  buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: update retrofit:2.4.0 to retrofit:2.9.0 and also update retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0 to retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0 and scalars library already updated. This is versions are working for me. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: But this error doesnt occur only for retrofit any dependency I add to the gradle it displays the same error that it cannot get the dependency and displays disable offline mode and sync but I tried that too but the same error persists